# VBA: Code review - Skip 1st line of a sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to understand how to skip the 1st row (A) of my sheet when i use below code which check whether any value available on my excel sheet.

```
Sub IsActiveSheetEmpty()
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Then
       MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is empty"
    Else
      MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is not empty"
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (does implicitly reference active sheet so you may want to explicitly state the worksheet name.) It will use the last row and column for which ever version of Excel you are using:

```
Sub IsActiveSheetEmpty()

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, Cells.Columns.Count))) = 0 Then
       MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is empty"
    Else
      MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is not empty"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Mention of implicit ActiveSheet reference gets my vote!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I can thank RubberDuck for my obsession with implicit references!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should be a boolean-returning function rather than sub, but:

```
Option explicit

Sub IsActiveSheetEmpty()

Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws = Activesheet

With ws

If application.CountA(.range(.range("B1"),.cells(.rows.count,.columns.count))) = 0 Then
MsgBox .Name & " is empty"
Else
MsgBox .Name & " is not empty"
End If

End with

End Sub
```

Untested, written on mobile. Does it do what you want?

**Edit: Think you mean column A?**

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Sub IsActiveSheetEmpty()
   Dim myRange As Range
   Set myRange = Range("A2",Cells(2,1).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell))

   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) = 0 Then
      MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is empty"
   Else
      MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is not empty"
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub IsActiveSheetEmpty()
If WorksheetFunction.CountA("A2:A5") = 0 Then 'skips A1
   MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is empty"
Else
  MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & " is not empty"
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks @pokemon_Man, And sorry for the question, I was expected to skip the Row 'A' completely and check rest of Rows and Columns